# can i give multiple names in a embed message command nextcord

Tags: discord, discord.py

So I want to make my bot give a youtube link with multiple names of commands

````
@client.command(aliases=['youtube', 'yt'])
async def youtube (ctx):
    embed = nextcord.Embed(
        title="Youtube", url="https://www.youtube.com/",
        description="Enjoy the videos and music you love, upload original content, and share it all with friends, family, and the world on YouTube.",
        colour = nextcord.Colour.brand_red(),
        
    )
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)```

[the is an error][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrzG5.png
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what I assume nextcord is (an extension of discord.py?), you cannot have a command alias of a command that already exists. The command is already called `youtube`, so you cannot you cannot have `youtube` as an alias. You'll need to remove it.

```py
@client.command(aliases=['yt'])
async def youtube (ctx):
    embed = nextcord.Embed(
        title="Youtube", 
        url="https://www.youtube.com/",
        description="Enjoy the videos and music you love, upload original content, and share it all with friends, family, and the world on YouTube.",
        colour = nextcord.Colour.brand_red(),
    )
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```